# Where is root-level and app-level in Cordova Project

Tags: cordova, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm confuse with path directory of root-level and app-level as mentioned in thid docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries

There is 2 different file build.gradle that i have to modify. But in the cordova projects, there is 3 build.gradle's . Which one i should edit?

```
./platforms/android/build.gradle
./platforms/android/CordovaLib/build.gradle
./plugins/cordova-plugin-firebase/src/android/build.gradle
```

FYI: i have build error with FCM.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out and solve the FCM issue?

Comment: Did anyone ever get an answer for this, I can't find anything about it

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked for me

1. Add the classpath to both `build.gradle` files (`project root > CordovaLib > build.gradle` and `project root > build.gradle`)
2. Add the app level update to `project root > build.gradle`
3. Sync and test

***Note: was only able to get this working after building and importing the project into android studio***